# best way to display values when mixing php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have a controller.js which makes a JSON call to a php file. In the php file i need to see a few values, when I echo it it does not show.

here my code:

```
//Controller.js
show: function(data) {
var self = this,
salesquoteguid = data && data.salesquoteguid || self.salesquoteguid;

$.getJSON('data/load.salesquote.php', {salesquoteguid: salesquoteguid}, function(data) {
self.set('salesquoteguid', salesquoteguid);
self.set('content', data);
self.set('pricemethod', data.pricemethod);
self.set('salesquoteitems', data.salesquoteitems);
    });
},

//data/load.salesquote.php
function getSalesquoteitemRecords(//some parameter)
{
   if ($contentlocation = App::getContentLocation()) {
     $contentlocation.= 'images/item/';
 $targetDirExists = PATH_CLEVVA.$contentlocation;
 $targetDir = PATH_CLEVVA_DISPLAY.$contentlocation;
}
   echo $contentlocation;  // I need to see this value 
}
```

when i refresh my page i get a "NO" displayed at the top???

what is the best way to display values when you mix js with php?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
echo $contentlocation;
```

to:

```
echo json_encode($contentlocation);
```

because `$.getJSON` requires the script to send JSON.

Comment: i have the echo in the php part and changed it to your suggestion but still nothing on my page except the "NO"

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that displays "NO", so I have no idea where that's coming from.

Comment: Actually, I don't see where your code displays the data returned from the server. Is that what `self.set('content', data)` does?

Comment: yikes i just started working on this code and also have no idea where the "NO" comes from. wrt the self.set probably. i guess i will have to ask someone here.